# Access control to different users - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

In my app I have two types of users - admin and teacher. In my AuthController I have this :

```
public function getLogin() {
    return view('auth.login');
}

public function postLogin(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    if(Auth::attempt([
        'username' => $request->input('username'),
        'password' => $request->input('password'),
        'type' => 'admin'
    ])) {
        return redirect ('admin');
    }

    if(Auth::attempt([
        'username' => $request->input('username'),
        'password' => $request->input('password'),
        'type' => 'teacher'
    ])) {
        return redirect ('educator/account');
    }


    return redirect('login')->with('message', [
        'type' => 'danger',
        'message' => 'Грешно потребителско име или парола!'
    ]);
}

public function getLogout() {
    Auth::logout();

    return redirect('login');
}
```

But when I'm logged in as a user with type teacher if i go to **http://localhost/school_system/public/admin** I automatically go to the admin panel without asking for username and password. I want if I want to go to the admin panel from the teacher account this to happen with asking for username and password, how can I make this?

My routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']
], function () {
    Route::group([
        'prefix' => 'admin',
        'namespace' => 'Admin'
    ], function () {
        Route::controller('student', 'StudentsController');
        Route::controller('profile', 'ProfilesController');
        Route::controller('class', 'ClassesController');
        Route::controller('subjects', 'SubjectsController');
        Route::controller('teacher', 'TeachersController');
        Route::controller('marktype', 'MarkTypeController');
        Route::controller('rules', 'RuleController');
        Route::get('{slug?}', 'PageController@getView');


    });
});
     Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']
       ], function () {
           Route::group([
               'prefix' => 'educator',
              'namespace' => 'Educator'
         ], function () {
               Route::controller('account', 'AccountController');
               Route::get('{slug?}', 'EducatorController@getView');
          });

       });
```

Thanks ^^

Comment: [Laravel 5 Simple ACL manager](https://gist.github.com/drawmyattention/8cb599ee5dc0af5f4246)

Comment: You have to make some middleware for specific user role and in route you have to make route group for every role and define these middleware

Comment: But here my users get its type in the table itself, like this:
`Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('first_name', 20);
            $table->string('last_name', 20);
            $table->integer('class_id')
                ->unsigned()
                ->nullable();
            $table->enum('type', ['admin', 'educator', 'student']);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an "adminmiddleware" : `php artisan make:middleware AdminMiddleware`
Example of code you can use

```
if ($request->user()->type != 'admin')
{
    return redirect('home');
}
```

and in the route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin']...
```

Finished ;)

Comment: But i dont have class `admin` ?